# Elegant method to omit fraction formatting number if number is an integer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am formatting floating point numbers and right now I have the %0.2f formatter, but I'd like to omit the .00 if the floating point number is an even integer.

Of course I can think of string replacing the .00, but that's crude.

I found that the description of NSNumber also does something similar:

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:_paragraphSpacing];
[retString appendFormat:@"margin-bottom:%@px;", number];
```

This this does hover not limit the post comma digits. if the number is 1234.56789 then the description will output that.

So my question is, is there a just as simple way - possibly without having to create an NSNumber object - to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1):

Since floating-point numbers aren't exact, there's no guarantee that your number will actually be an integer. You can, however, check if it's within a reasonably small distance from an integer value. And of course you don't need an NSNumber for this. (Generally speaking, NSNumber is not used for formatting, its purpose is representing a primitive C type, either integral or floating-point types, using an Objective-C object.)

```
#include <math.h>

- (NSString *)stringFromFloat:(float)f
{
    const float eps = 1.0e-6;
    if (abs(round(f) - f) < eps) {
        // assume an integer
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"margin-bottom: %.0fpx", round(f)];
    } else {
        // assume a real number
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"margin-bottom: %.2fpx", f];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use C function `modff` to get the fraction part and test it:

```
float fractionPart = 0.;
modff(_paragraphSpacing, &fractionPart);
if( fabsf(fractionPart) < 0.01 ) {
  // format as integer
  [retString appendFormat:@"margin-bottom:%d", (int)_paragraphSpacing];
} else {
  // format as float
  [retString appendFormat:@"margin-bottom:%0.2f", _paragraphSpacing];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a formatter:

```
NSNumberFormatter* formatter= [NSNumberFormatter new];
formatter.numberStyle= NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
formatter.maximumFractionDigits=2;
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:_paragraphSpacing];
[retString appendFormat:@"margin-bottom:%@;", [formatter stringFromNumber: number]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `NSNumberFormatter` for this:

```
static NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = nil;
if (numberFormatter == nil) {
    numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0;
    numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
    numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = NO;
}
NSString *formattedNumberString = [numberFormatter
     stringForNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble: _paragraphSpacing]];
```